# Removing a string from url in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to remove a specific string from URL in .htaccess file.

For example my root URL is `www.example.com`. If someone puts `www.example.com/#` , it should redirect to root URL.

I have tried with

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^#/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The hash in the URL isn`t sent to the server when requesting a page, so you can't use redirect rules like that. It's client-side only.

You can change the url only with javascript:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/, ""));
}
```